Electron отображает текст вместо страницы
Я пишу проект на Electron. Мой файл main.js выглядит следующим образом:
const electron = require("electron") 
const app = electron.app 
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow 
var mainWindow = null 

app.on('ready', function () { 
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600}) 
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
})

Когда я запускаю проект, все работает должным образом:

Однако если я перейду на другую страницу (нажав "список пользователей"), то страница будет отображаться не как полноценный раздел, а как просто текст:

С чем это может быть связано? На всякий случай, файл package.json выглядит следующим образом:
{
  "name": "coursedb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^30.1.0"
  }
}


А что у Вас PHP делает в Electron?

@Simon делал сайт, пришлось срочно переделать в приложение

Ну так PHP там не работает, по крайней мере из коробки
